# Create an array of Objects in Java

Tags: java, arrays, object

I've got this code started as an assignment for class. We are to set up a class that will create an array of objects. We are supposed to have two constructors so the array can be initialized with a given size, or a default size of 100. Here is what I have so far

```
public class Set {

    private int maxObjects;
    private int sz;

    public Set(int maxObjects) {
        this.maxObjects = maxObjects;
        this.sz = maxObjects;
        Object[] a = new Object[maxObjects];
    }

    public Set() {
        this.maxObjects = 100;
        this.sz = 100;
        Object[] a = new Object[100];
    }

    public void add(Object object) {
        a[0] = Object;
    }
```

The problem I'm coming across is that it's not seeing `a` as a variable in the `add()` method. Also the arrays are supposed to be initialized with a set capacity, but as empty, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's not seeing `a` as a variable in the `add()` method

Your problem is that `a` is *declared* in the `Set` constructor, so it's local to the constructor. This means that it can't be used outside of the constructor (such as from the `add` method).

The solution is pretty simple. Declare `a` with your other fields:

```
public class Set {

    private int maxObjects;
    private int sz;
    private Object[] a;

    public Set(int maxObjects) {
        this.maxObjects = maxObjects;
        this.sz = maxObjects;
        this.a = new Object[maxObjects];
    }

    public Set() {
        this.maxObjects = 100;
        this.sz = 100;
        this.a = new Object[100];
    }

    public void add(Object object) {
        a[0] = object;
    }
}
```

I recommend reading up on scopes in Java (a simple Google search will produce help there).

> Also the arrays are supposed to be initialized with a set capacity, but as empty.

This is done by default. For an array of any non-primitive type, the array's elements are all initialized to `null`. Here, an all-`null` array is essentially an empty array. Calling `new Object[capacity]` is doing this for you.

Answer (score 4):

You should define `a` the same place you defined maxObjects and sz.

```
private Object[] a;
```

Then place this in your constructors:

```
a = new Object[maxObjects];
```

Read about the [scope of variables](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html).

Comment: You don't need the second half of your statement, that would initialize the array with a size of 0. The array reference 'a' will be reassigned in the constructor. Assigning it in the top will just cause more work for the garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close to having this correct. The problem you have is related to the scope of variables. Examine closer the scope of variable a.

Also you have a typo in your add method.

```
a[0] = Object
```

should be

```
a[0] = object
```

(with a lower case o)

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

- `a` should be a field
- your default constructor should call the other constructor
- typo

Try this:

```
public class Set {

    private int maxObjects;
    private int sz;
    private Object[] a;

    public Set(int maxObjects) {
        this.maxObjects = maxObjects;
        this.sz = maxObjects;
        a = new Object[maxObjects];
    }

    public Set() {
        this(100);  // fyi, this is the syntax for calling another constuctor
    }

    public void add(Object object) {
        a[0] = object;
    }
}
```